# How do you transfer environment variable from one docker container to another?

Tags: mongodb, docker, networking, environment-variables

I want to fetch the IP from a docker container and transfer it to another container to then be printed in Python. I'm using docker-compose but I'm having trouble setting the .env file, having the docker-compose env variables fetch from the .env file and print it in the Python file.

This is to automate the process fetching the IP Address of one container and using it within another

---

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  api:
    image: benjaminlandry/swagger_falsy_libs:falsy_libs
    build: ./api
    environment:
      - MONGOIP =$MONGOIP
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    container_name: api
  mongodb:
    build: ./mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGOIP = $MONGOIP
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    container_name: mongodb
```

---

bash script:

```
MONGOIP=`docker inspect $container_mongo | jq '.[].NetworkSettings.Networks.bridge.IPAddress'`
```

---

.env:

```
MONGOIP=$MONGOIP
```

---

abc.py:

```
mongoIP= os.environ.get('MONGOIP')
print(mongoIP)
```

Comment: It cannot be through command line. The env variable needs to be transfered through script because I do not have the IP Address, nor do I manually want to input it each time.

Comment: You can just use the mongo compose service name `mongodb`, docker will resolve it to the correct ip.